# IdeaVim: is there a way to change background color when changing from command to insert mode and back etc? e.g. each mode own bg color

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

IdeaVim: is there a way to change background color when changing from command to insert mode and back etc? e.g. each mode own bg color?

currently I can only see it via the caret, and the caret is blinking right, so I often dont realize that I'm in insert mode instead of command mode and vice versa, would be great to have the ability to see that more visually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionally and we don't have currently plans to support something like that. 
You can add 'set showmode' to your '~/.ideavimrc' to see the current mode in the status bar.

Comment: that little indicator at the bottom left is a bit tiny but I guess its not easy at all to implement it. Anyway, I'm enjoying ideavim so far. One thing that bothered me for a long time is integration "extend selection" and "jump to end of selection" doesnt work if caret is in middle of selection. My current workaround is cut paste the entire thing to go there. To normal selection jumping with o or `> doesnt work as the caret is in the middle of things.... a lil pity